# Can a Bitten Master also be a Slave?

Tags: continuous-integration

Using [Bitten](http://bitten.edgewall.org/) , can I use one machine (as master and slave) if I only have one target platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had no problems to do it.

We just launch 'bitten-slave' as usual, but on the master server.

Don't hesitate to specify any difficulties if you encountered any.